# Mongodb: Rename json element in array based on another element

Tags: json, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to flatten some JSON data so that I can send it in CSV format to some clients. I'm nearly there...Using the aggregation framework in MongoDB, so far, I have managed to get it to output this for each customer:

```
    { 
"_id" : ObjectId("5a69aafefe0428ada3c1cb9d"), 
"company_id" : NumberInt(8), 
"year" : NumberInt(2017),  
"customer_id" : "1691", 
...
...
"department_id" : "11",
"Stat" : [
    {
        "@value" : NumberInt(7), 
        "@attributes" : {
            "name" : "A"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "@value" : NumberInt(3), 
        "@attributes" : {
            "name" : "B"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "@value" : NumberInt(14), 
        "@attributes" : {
            "name" : "C"
        }
    } 
]
}
```

However what I would ideally like is to get this for each customer:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a69aafefe0428ada3c1cb9d"), 
"company_id" : NumberInt(8), 
"year" : NumberInt(2017),
"customer_id" : "1691", 
...
...
"department_id" : "11",
"A"  : NumberInt(7),
"B"  : NumberInt(3),
"C"  : NumberInt(14)
}
```

Basically, I need to move the array elements up to the root level and also rename the element @value based on the @attributes.name field. The Stat array is also quite large and has over 50 stats in it.

What I've done so far has helped, and I suppose I can finish the rest up in python or vba in Excel, however I was hoping to be able to do this all in one step. I'm really new at MongoDB and don't have any javascript experience, so any pointers (tips/ links to tutorials/advice) would be really useful.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this aggregation, if you are using mongo 3.6.x

```
db.col.aggregate([
    { $addFields : {Stat : {$map : {input : "$Stat", as : "s", in : {$objectToArray : "$$s"}}}}},
    { $addFields : {Stat : {$map : {input : "$Stat", as : "s", in : [{$arrayElemAt : ["$$s.v.name",0]},{$arrayElemAt : ["$$s.v",0]}]}}}},
    { $addFields : {Stat : {$arrayToObject : "$Stat"}}},
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ "$$ROOT", "$Stat" ] } }},
    { $project : {Stat : 0}}
])
```

result

```
> db.col.aggregate([
...     { $addFields : {Stat : {$map : {input : "$Stat", as : "s", in : {$objectToArray : "$$s"}}}}},
...     { $addFields : {Stat : {$map : {input : "$Stat", as : "s", in : [{$arrayElemAt : ["$$s.v.name",0]},{$arrayElemAt : ["$$s.v",0]}]}}}},
...     { $addFields : {Stat : {$arrayToObject : "$Stat"}}},
...     { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ "$$ROOT","$Stat" ] } }},
...     { $project : {Stat : 0}}
... ]).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a69aafefe0428ada3c1cb9d"),
    "company_id" : 8,
    "year" : 2017,
    "customer_id" : "1691",
    "department_id" : "11",
    "A" : 7,
    "B" : 3,
    "C" : 14
}
>
```

sample document

```
> db.col.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a69aafefe0428ada3c1cb9d"),
    "company_id" : 8,
    "year" : 2017,
    "customer_id" : "1691",
    "department_id" : "11",
    "Stat" : [
        {
            "@value" : 7,
            "@attributes" : {
                "name" : "A"
            }
        },
        {
            "@value" : 3,
            "@attributes" : {
                "name" : "B"
            }
        },
        {
            "@value" : 14,
            "@attributes" : {
                "name" : "C"
            }
        }
    ]
}
>
```

Comment: Brilliant, that worked a treat. Thank you. I tried using addfields before but couldn't get it to work. Just out of interest could you recommend a good book/tutorial/resource, other than the mongodb documentation, where I can learn a bit more about what you just did there.

Comment: @JCB I'm also learning mongoDB, official documentation is good